# Container-less java application in openshift PaaS

Tags: java, jetty, openshift

Is it possible to deploy container-less java application in Openshift PaaS? Everybody knows that java server application can be created using embedded jetty which bypasses the need of any java application server like jboss/weblogic, hence saving a lot more resources in terms of memory in a resource constraint environment like cloud. As Openshift started supporting vert.x, I am curious is it possible to deploy container-less java application there?

The intended application logic is more or less like this : http://www.jamesward.com/2012/08/13/containerless-spring-mvc

I know openshift does not offer cartridges like this, but I am eager to know is it possible by creating a diy cartridge?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the DIY cartridge and use action hooks to start your application any way that you want to.